# Is there any "middleware" or npm package Convert flat JSON file to hierarchical json data?

Tags: javascript, npm, dom-events, npm-scripts

I want convert flat-Json to hierarchical,
or I'm converting excel to Json first and then try to make JSON Object hierarchy.
I want convert flat-Json to hierarchical json object of nth level.

```
Is there any middleware  that conver Flat JSON to hirerachy JSON object.
{ "Name": "SAM", "Department": "CO", "Year": "2018"},
{ "Name": "SAM", "Address": "Mumbai", "Type": "Permanent"},
{ "Name": "John", "Department": "CE", "Year": "2018" },
{ "Name": "John", "Address": "Delhi", "Type": "Permanent" }

Expected Out-Put:

[{    
    "Name" : "SAM",   
    "Department": "CO",
    "Year": "2018"
    "children" : [{
                "Name": "SAM", 
                "Address": "Mumbai", 
                "Type": "Permanent"                
            }]
},
{    
    "Name" : "John",   
    "Department": "CE",
    "Year": "2018"
    "children" : [{
                "Name": "John", 
                "Address": "Delhi", 
                "Type": "Permanent"                
            }]
}]
```

Comment: Do you really want an external library to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: It's a pretty easy, but inefficient `Array.reduce()` loop. Add the children property, filter the original array for all those children, add them to the property, repeat. The irony being that the original array is easier to work with than once it's nested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hierarchical json from flat with parent ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376251/hierarchical-json-from-flat-with-parent-id)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  Thank you  .. Yes i Want external package like **npm  xls-to-json**

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function you are looking

```
var arry = [{ "Id": "1", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "", "attr": "abc" },
           { "Id": "2", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "1", "attr": "abc" },
           { "Id": "3", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "2", "attr": "abc" },
           { "Id": "4", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "2", "attr": "abc" }];
function convert(array){
  var map = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var obj = array[i];
    obj.items= [];

    map[obj.Id] = obj;

    var parent = obj.Parent || '-';
    if(!map[parent]){
        map[parent] = {
            items: []
        };
    }
    map[parent].items.push(obj);
  }
  return map['-'].items;
}

var r = convert(arry);
```

Result

```
[{
    "Id" : "1",
    "Name" : "abc",
    "Parent" : "",
    "attr" : "abc",
    "children" : [{
                "Id" : "2",
                "Name" : "abc",
                "Parent" : "1",
                "attr" : "abc",
                "children" : [{
                            "Id" : "3",
                            "Name" : "abc",
                            "Parent" : "2",
                            "attr" : "abc",
                            "children" : []
                        }, {
                            "Id" : "4",
                            "Name" : "abc",
                            "Parent" : "2",
                            "attr" : "abc",
                            "children" : []
                        }]
            }]
}]
```

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376430/1826429

Comment: Thank you .. You are right but i want npm  package or middleware , So i can pass my json object to middleware and get expected result that will clean or reduce my code. like npm **xls-to-json** thank you very much...

Comment: Is there any middleware  that conver Flat JSON to hirerachy JSON object.